# Laptop not booting to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mbr, windows-installation, fedora-17

I installed a fresh Windows 7 overwriting Fedora 17.
The installation was successful, but the laptop is not now booting.
It's showing a black screen with a blinking cursor.

Comment: Do you see a GRUB start-up menu when you boot the laptop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply repair your MBR of windows

- Insert your DVD of Windows 7
- WHile Booting, click on Repair your computer
- Now in Command prompt
- Type the following Command

Bootrec /FixMbr    // If you have Damaged MBR

Bootrec /Fixboot   // If you’r MBR is having problem or Missing.

Bootrec /Rebuild  //If you’re MBR is Compressed or unable to repair

You can find the detailed process here at [How to Fix/repair/Rebuild MBR in Windows 7/8](http://www.inteligentcomp.com/2013/06/how-to-repair-fix-mbr-windows-7-8.html)

Answer (score 0):

Windows should have modfied your MBR, but if it didn't you might try erasing your drive from the BIOS or from a linux LiveCD or something.  Then re-install windows.  Key is deleting the making your whole drive unallocated space, formatting a partition will not work because it works around existing information on the drive, like the MBR leaving it intact.  Erasing a drive completely and resetting it back so it is empty should fix your problem.

Otherwise, sourcing a method to fix your MBR like @karel mentioned is definitely the way to go.  There are many options out there if you search for them.